# Iterate through a json in groups

Tags: jquery, django-views

I have this json returned by an ajax request in my app,

```
{"info": {"pat_gender": "f", 
          "obtained_pmh": true, 
          "organized": false, 
          "hpi_selected_alleviating": true, 
          "greeted_patients": true, 
          "echoed_patients_words": false,
          "allowed_pt_to_finish_thoughts": true,
          "grade": "Excellent"
        } }
```

I want to loop through the items but in groups sorting true and false fields i.e

```
{"info": {
          "pat_gender": "f", 

           //from here GROUP1
          "obtained_pmh": true, 
          "organized": false, 
          "hpi_selected_alleviating": true, 

           //GROUP2
          "greeted_patients": true, 
          "echoed_patients_words": false,
          "allowed_pt_to_finish_thoughts": true,


          "grade": "Excellent"
        } }
```

I want to have the fields in group 1 sorted in two lists (True and false), and also group2 sorted in the same way.
How best can I do this?

Comment: JS objects (and by extension, JSON dictionaries) don't have a concept of "key order" built in.  You'll need to have your own list of fields in the order you want to check them.  What do you mean by "sorted" in this case, though?

Comment: @cHao  In sorting, I mean create the two groups of fields then in each group, separate the fields into T and F.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your properties and push keys with `true` values to a property named "group1" and push keys with `false` values to a property named group2:

```
obj.group1 = [];
obj.group2 = [];
for p in obj {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        if (obj[p] === true) {
            obj.group1.push[p];
        } else if (obj[p] === false) {
            obj.group2.push[p];
        }
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve all keys in `obj.group1` by iterating over the array.

Comment: This is working well in sorting them. Is there a way I can group the fields in two GROUP1 and GROUP2 as shown above, then in each groups  (1 and 2) I sort into GROUP1_T and GROUP1_F and GROUP2_T and GROUP2_F as you have done? Maybe I rename the fields such that GROUP1 has a certain naming convention and also do the same for GROUP2. Is it possible?

Comment: @AlexKasina It looks like I misunderstood the question. What is your criteria for separating keys into group1 or group2?

Comment: yes. I wanted to separate those two groups of fields, then in each group, I apply your code above.